# Query performance is affected by boolean literals?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework, linq

I would like to know if boolean literals affect query performance in Entity Framework, because I was told they do, although I couldn't find any material that agreed with that and I think it's redundant to use them...

An example of what I did is written below:

```
_context.Entity.Where(e => e.Blocked);
```

And I was told the approach below would be better because of performance:

```
_context.Entity.Where(e => e.Blocked == true);
```

Sorry for any English mistakes, it's not my native language. :/

Comment: Did you test it? If so, what were your results?

Comment: Yes, and I ran some of our integration tests and there wasn't much of a difference between them...

Comment: And who told you there was a difference, and what was their justification for the difference?

Comment: @PigStorm I assume that there could be difference in the resulting query. It is possible to log SQL queries, produced by Entity Framework. This is what you need to understand if there is a difference, assuming that you do this out of a curiousity. Because if you are worried about the performance, then it is definitely a [**premature optimization**](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/). You don't want to write weird code just because it will save you 100ms per hour and will never become a bottleneck, do you? :)

Comment: @Servy it was another dev in my team, he said that the query that would be generated using the literal would be "more direct", it would create something like "Entity.Blocked = 1" instead of verifying if it is null or something like that, he wasn't very sure about what would happen either, but that if it was with the literal it would be better.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev thanks for the enlightenment, I think it might be a premature optimization too. Will check it with my team and see what we decide on it. Besides that, yes, I am a bit curious about it now, so will try to investigate on how the query is generated in both scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major issues of Entity Framework regarding the performance, are related to the way that query is developed by a developer. If the query is written properly, so there is no need to worry.

The simplest way to ensure about the generated query is to use SQL Profiler. You can simply track your query there. For further studying you can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler-templates-and-permissions?view=sql-server-2017)

In your case both generated queries are the same.

I developed an example code below.

Suppose these queries

```
var q1 = _roleRepository.GetAll().Where(q => q.IsDeleted).ToList();

var q2 = _roleRepository.GetAll().Where(q => q.IsDeleted == true).ToList();
```

the results tracking in SQL profiler are :

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[NormalizedName] AS [NormalizedName], 
        [Extent1].[TenantId] AS [TenantId], 
        [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Extent1].[DisplayName] AS [DisplayName], 
        [Extent1].[IsStatic] AS [IsStatic], 
        [Extent1].[IsDefault] AS [IsDefault], 
        [Extent1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
        [Extent1].[DeleterUserId] AS [DeleterUserId], 
        [Extent1].[DeletionTime] AS [DeletionTime], 
        [Extent1].[LastModificationTime] AS [LastModificationTime], 
        [Extent1].[LastModifierUserId] AS [LastModifierUserId], 
        [Extent1].[CreationTime] AS [CreationTime], 
        [Extent1].[CreatorUserId] AS [CreatorUserId]
        FROM [dbo].[AbpRoles] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ((([Extent1].[TenantId] IS NULL) AND (@DynamicFilterParam_000003 IS NULL)) OR (([Extent1].[TenantId] IS NOT NULL) AND (([Extent1].[TenantId] = @DynamicFilterParam_000003) OR (([Extent1].[TenantId] IS NULL) AND (@DynamicFilterParam_000003 IS NULL)))) ) AND (([Extent1].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_000001) ) AND ([Extent1].[IsDeleted] = 1)',N'@DynamicFilterParam_000003 int,@DynamicFilterParam_000004 bit,@DynamicFilterParam_000001 bit,@DynamicFilterParam_000002 bit',@DynamicFilterParam_000003=1,@DynamicFilterParam_000004=NULL,@DynamicFilterParam_000001=0,@DynamicFilterParam_000002=NULL

        exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[NormalizedName] AS [NormalizedName], 
        [Extent1].[TenantId] AS [TenantId], 
        [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Extent1].[DisplayName] AS [DisplayName], 
        [Extent1].[IsStatic] AS [IsStatic], 
        [Extent1].[IsDefault] AS [IsDefault], 
        [Extent1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
        [Extent1].[DeleterUserId] AS [DeleterUserId], 
        [Extent1].[DeletionTime] AS [DeletionTime], 
        [Extent1].[LastModificationTime] AS [LastModificationTime], 
        [Extent1].[LastModifierUserId] AS [LastModifierUserId], 
        [Extent1].[CreationTime] AS [CreationTime], 
        [Extent1].[CreatorUserId] AS [CreatorUserId]
        FROM [dbo].[AbpRoles] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ((([Extent1].[TenantId] IS NULL) AND (@DynamicFilterParam_000003 IS NULL)) OR (([Extent1].[TenantId] IS NOT NULL) AND (([Extent1].[TenantId] = @DynamicFilterParam_000003) OR (([Extent1].[TenantId] IS NULL) AND (@DynamicFilterParam_000003 IS NULL)))) ) AND (([Extent1].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_000001) ) AND (1 = [Extent1].[IsDeleted])',N'@DynamicFilterParam_000003 int,@DynamicFilterParam_000004 bit,@DynamicFilterParam_000001 bit,@DynamicFilterParam_000002 bit',@DynamicFilterParam_000003=1,@DynamicFilterParam_000004=NULL,@DynamicFilterParam_000001=0,@DynamicFilterParam_000002=NULL
```

exactly the same !